# Hermitian adjoint for 3-vectors; should the energy-momentum 4-vector be written as $P^\mu=\left(p^0,\,p^i\right)$ or $\left(p^0,\,\vec {p}\right)$?

Tags: notation, physics, quantum-mechanics, index-notation, quantum-field-theory

> Consider the real Klein-Gordon scalar;
>
> Taking the Hermitian Hamiltonian, and (spatial) momentum operators as
>
> $$\hat H = \int \frac{d^3 \vec p}{\left(2 \pi\right)^32E(\vec p)}E(\vec p)\hat a^\dagger(\vec p)\hat a(\vec p)\tag{1}$$
> $$\hat P^i = \int \frac{d^3 \vec p}{\left(2 \pi\right)^32E(\vec p)}p^i\hat a^\dagger(\vec p)\hat a(\vec p)\tag{2}$$
> and writing the total 4-momentum operator $\hat P^\mu=\left(\hat H, \hat{P}^i\right)$, show that these commute with the ladder operators as
>
> $$\left[\hat P^\mu,\, \hat a(\vec q)\right]=-q^\mu \hat a(\vec q)\tag{A}$$
> and
> $$\left[\hat P^\mu,\, \hat a^\dagger(\vec q)\right]=q^\mu \hat a^\dagger(\vec q)\tag{B}$$
> where $q^\mu=\left(E(\vec q),\,\vec q\right)$

---

After a long calculation (which I would prefer not to typeset) I can show the first relation, $(\mathrm{A})$. I can also show that
$$\left[\hat H,\, \hat a(\vec q)\right]=-E(\vec q)\hat a(\vec q)\tag{3}$$ and
$$\left[\hat P^i,\, \hat a(\vec q)\right]=-q^i\hat a(\vec q)\tag{4}$$

Now instead of repeating a similar calculation to show $(\mathrm{B})$ I would like to use $(\mathrm{A})$ instead and use the fact that
$$\left[\hat P^\mu,\, \hat a(\vec q)\right]=\left[\hat H +\hat P^i,\, \hat a(\vec q)\right]$$
$$=\left[\hat H,\, \hat a(\vec q)\right]\stackrel{\color{red}{?}}{+}\left[\hat P^i,\, \hat a(\vec q)\right]=-E(\vec q)\hat a(\vec q)-q^i\hat a(\vec q)\stackrel{\color{red}{?}}{=}-q^\mu \hat a(\vec q)\tag{5}$$

Taking the Hermitian adjoint of both sides of $(5)$,
$$\left[\hat P^\mu,\, \hat a(\vec q)\right]^\dagger=\left(\left[\hat H,\, \hat a(\vec q)\right]+\left[\hat P^i,\, \hat a(\vec q)\right]\right)^\dagger$$
$$=\left[\hat H,\, \hat a(\vec q)\right]^\dagger+\left[\hat P^i,\, \hat a(\vec q)\right]^\dagger$$
$$=\left(\hat H\hat a(\vec q)-\hat a(\vec q)\hat H\right)^\dagger+\left(\hat P^i\hat a(\vec q)-\hat a(\vec q)\hat P^i\right)^\dagger$$
$$=\left(\hat H\hat a(\vec q)\right)^\dagger-\left(\hat a(\vec q)\hat H\right)^\dagger+\left(\hat P^i\hat a(\vec q)\right)^\dagger-\left(\hat a(\vec q)\hat P^i\right)^\dagger$$
$$=\left(\hat a^\dagger(\vec q)\hat H -\hat H\hat a^\dagger(\vec q)\right)+\left(\hat a^\dagger(\vec q)\hat P^i -\hat P^i\hat a^\dagger(\vec q)\right)$$
$$=\left[\hat a^\dagger(\vec q),\,\hat H\right]+\left[\hat a^\dagger(\vec q),\,\hat P^i\right]=-\left(\left[\hat H,\,\hat a^\dagger(\vec q)\right]+\left[\hat P^i,\,\hat a^\dagger(\vec q)\right]\right)$$
$$=-\left(E(\vec q)\hat a(\vec q)\right)^\dagger-\left({\color{red}{q^i}}\hat a(\vec q)\right)^\dagger=-E(\vec q)\hat a^\dagger(\vec q)-\hat a^\dagger(\vec q){\color{red}{q^i}^\dagger}\ne q^\mu \hat a^\dagger(\vec q)\tag{6}$$

I've written many steps on purpose to show that it is the presence of the 3-momentum vector, $q^i$, colored red that is causing the problem. Typically in QM/QFT the Hermitian adjoint, $\dagger$, acts as an invertible map between the bras and kets as elements of a Hilbert space, which, in Dirac notation would look like for states $|\phi\rangle$, $|\psi\rangle$
$$|\phi\rangle=\hat O|\psi\rangle\overbrace{\iff}^\dagger\langle\phi|=\langle\psi|\hat O^\dagger\tag{7}$$

*Here is the problem*: I do not know how to interpret the notation of this $q^i$ object, is it a vector or a vector component? I'm confused as physicists sometimes abuse notation and write a 4-vector as $P^\mu=\left(p^0,\,p^i\right)$ or $P^\mu=\left(p^0,\,\vec p\right)$ which I find very annoying.

I don't understand whether to switch the order and take the Hermitian adjoint for the second term in parentheses after the first equality (shown in red) of eqn. $(6)$ **or**, treat $q^i$ as a component of a vector and not switch the order.

In short, how does one know when to interpret say $x^j$ as a component or a 3-vector and hence when to switch the order when taking the Hermitian adjoint?

---

### Update

Now a comment and an answer both say that the notation $p^i$ is a vector component (the ith component) and *not* a vector. That said, why am I still seeing statements like the following:

[image: Inner product]

Hence the confusion. Sorry I don't have a source for the extract above.

I've been told in a comment by @Gonçalo that $\hat{P}^\mu\neq\hat H +\hat P^i$, which means that the first line of my eqn. $(5)$ is incorrect. For the second line of eqn. $(5)$ I have put question marks above the parts for which I am unsure. Basically, I don't think I can add commutators like that to get the result of eqn. $(\mathrm{A})$, namely,
$$\left[\hat P^\mu,\, \hat a(\vec q)\right]=-q^\mu\hat a(\vec q)$$ but I don't know how else to arrive at the result.

Any help would be most appreciated, thanks.

Comment: $p^{i}$ is the $i$-th component of the $3$-vector $\vec{p}$. $(p^0,p^i)$ is a shorthand notation for $(p^0,p^1,p^2,p^3)$, also written as $(p^0,\vec{p})$.

Comment: By the way, $\hat{P}^\mu\neq\hat H +\hat P^i$; $\hat{P}^\mu=\hat H$ if $\mu=0$, and $\hat{P}^\mu=\hat P^i$ if $\mu=i$ $(i=1,2,3)$.

Comment: @Gonçalo Thanks for the info, if $\hat{P}^\mu\neq\hat H +\hat P^i$ how do I combine $\hat H$ and $\hat P^i$ to get the commutator relation $\left[\hat P^\mu,\, \hat a^\dagger(\vec q)\right]=q^\mu \hat a^\dagger(\vec q)$? I used the same logic when proving $(\mathrm{A})$ then this means that is wrong also. I'm sorry but I'm very confused, would you please consider elaborating with an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a sign error in the last line of $(6)$.

$q^i$ are real-valued scalar coordinates and $E(q^1, q^2, q^3) = \left((q^1)^2+(q^2)^2+(q^3)^2+m^2\right)^{1/2}$ is also a real-valued scalar.

For any bounded operators $A,B$ on a Hilbert space
$$[A,B]^\dagger = (AB-BA)^\dagger=B^\dagger A^\dagger - A^\dagger B^\dagger = [B^\dagger,A^\dagger]=-[A^\dagger,B^\dagger]$$

Therefore
$$
\begin{split}
\left[\hat H,\, \hat a(\vec q)\right]^\dagger = \left[\hat a^\dagger(\vec q),\,\hat H^\dagger\right] &= \left[\hat a^\dagger(\vec q),\,\hat H\right] = -\left[\hat H,\,\hat a^\dagger(\vec q)\right]\\
\left[\hat P^i,\, \hat a(\vec q)\right]^\dagger = \left[\hat a^\dagger(\vec q),\,\hat P^{i\dagger}\right] &= \left[\hat a^\dagger(\vec q),\,\hat P^i\right] = -\left[\hat P^i,\,\hat a^\dagger(\vec q)\right]
\end{split}
$$
on account of $\hat H, \hat P^i$ being self-adjoint.

So from $(3), (4)$,
$$
\begin{split}
-\left[\hat H,\,\hat a^\dagger(\vec q)\right] &= (-E(\vec q)\hat a(\vec q))^\dagger =-E(\vec q)\hat a^\dagger(\vec q)\\
-\left[\hat P^i,\,\hat a^\dagger(\vec q)\right] &= (-q^i\hat a(\vec q))^\dagger=-q^i\hat a^\dagger(\vec q)
\end{split}
$$
which is $(B)$ after multiplying by $-1$.

Comment: Okay great, thanks for your answer. Suppose I had actually had a vector, $\vec q$. Would it then be correct to write $\left(\color{red}{\vec q}\hat a(\vec q)\right)^\dagger=\hat a^\dagger(\vec q){\color{red}{\vec q}^\dagger}$? I ask as this is what happens in eqn. $(7)$.

Comment: @FutureCop: Equation $(7)$ is correct.  You're mixing vectors $q^\mu$ in Minkowski space $\Bbb{R}^4$ and vectors $\phi, \psi$ in a Hilbert space $H$ that the operators $\hat a(\vec q)$ are acting on.  $\hat a(\vec q)$ is an operator-valued function of $q^1,q^2,q^3$.  There is a background $H$ such that $\hat a(\vec q):H\to H$ are operators.  So for all $\vec q\in\Bbb{R}^3$ and for all $\phi,\psi\in H$ it holds that $|\phi\rangle=\hat a(\vec{q})|\psi\rangle \iff \langle\phi|=\langle\psi|\hat a^\dagger(\vec{q})$.  The $\vec{q}$ doesn't adjoint.  It's not in $H$.  $q^1,q^2,q^3$ are not in $H$.

Comment: Very good explanation. In Gonçalo's second comment below my question it is stated that  $\hat{P}^\mu\neq\hat H +\hat P^i$. This means that what I wrote in equation $(5)$ of my question is wrong. That being the case, if I'm not allowed to add these commutators how does one combine the commutators $\left[\hat H,\, \hat a(\vec q)\right]$ and $\left[\hat P^i,\, \hat a(\vec q)\right]$ to get $\left[\hat P^\mu,\, \hat a(\vec q)\right]$?

Comment: In your last sentence you say that multiplying those equations in your last two lines by $-1$ is $(B)$. I'm not sure why adding commutators together should give the result. For instance, I'm not sure if the second line of my eqn $(5)$ is correct, in other words, is it true that $\left[\hat P^\mu,\, \hat a(\vec q)\right]=\left[\hat H,\, \hat a(\vec q)\right]+\left[\hat P^i,\, \hat a(\vec q)\right]=-E(\vec q)\hat a(\vec q)-q^i\hat a(\vec q)=-q^\mu \hat a(\vec q)$?

Comment: @FutureCop: They are four independent equations $\left[\hat H,\,\hat a(\vec q)\right]=-E(\vec q)\hat a(\vec q)$, $\left[\hat P^1,\,\hat a(\vec q)\right]=-q^1\hat a(\vec q)$, $\left[\hat P^2,\,\hat a(\vec q)\right]=-q^2\hat a(\vec q)$, $\left[\hat P^3,\,\hat a(\vec q)\right]=-q^3\hat a(\vec q)$.  There's no combining, just using an index $i$ or $\mu$ as notation to express multiple similar equations at once.  $\hat P^0:=\hat H$ and $q^0:=E(q^1,q^2,q^3)$.

Comment: I'm sorry I just don't understand. If I can't combine the commutators at all, how does one show that $\left[\hat P^\mu,\, \hat a(\vec q)\right]=-q^\mu\hat a(\vec q)$? Or is it really so obvious that you just write it down? Well, I regret to say that it is not very obvious to me. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @FutureCop: $\left[\hat P^\mu,\, \hat a(\vec q)\right]=-q^\mu\hat a(\vec q)$ is abbreviated notation for $4$ different equations obtained by substituting the values $0, 1, 2, 3$ for $\mu$.  There is no summation over $\mu$ implied.

Comment: Okay good. Just one more question - Does the four-vector, $\vec q^\mu$ commute with the ladder operator $\hat a(\vec q)$, in other words, is it true that $q^\mu\hat a(\vec q)=\hat a(\vec q)q^\mu$? I'm just slightly confused as although it's called a 'four-vector' we are treating it as if it is a *scalar* by commuting it with the $\hat a (\vec q)$.